# The cable of the tv antenna lies on the heater

Tags: cable

It might be a silly question, but the cable connected to my tv antenna is lying on my heater in my room.

The heater isn't particularly hot, but I was wondering if it might damage it in the long run.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely this would damage it - if it is a standard co-ax cable, then it can withstand much higher temperatures than your room heater will cause.

Mechanical failure is generally much more of a problem if you move the antenna a lot (wear on the cable as it enters the connectors is quite common)